# NameError: name 'Player' is not defined

Tags: python, class, nameerror

```py
class GameLogic(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._player = Player(7)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,move_count):
        self.move_count = move_count
```

This is not my original code. I simplified my original code to show my mistake.

Part of my original code is down below

```py
class GameLogic:
    def __init__(self, dungeon_name="game1.txt"):
        """Constructor of the GameLogic class.

        Parameters:
            dungeon_name (str): The name of the level.
        """
        self._dungeon = load_game(dungeon_name)
        self._dungeon_size = len(self._dungeon)

        #you need to implement the Player class first.
        self._player = Player(GAME_LEVELS[dungeon_name])

        #you need to implement the init_game_information() method for this.
        self._game_information = self.init_game_information()

        self._win = False


class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self,move_count):
        super().__init__()
        self.move_count = move_count
        self._name = 'Player(\'O\')'
        self._player_position = player_position
        self._inventory = []

    def get_id(self):
        entity_id = {self:'O'}
        return entity_id.get(self)

    def can_collide(self):
        return super().can_collide()

    def set_collide(self, collidable):
        return super().set_collide(collidable)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self._name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self._name)

    def get_position(self):
        return self._player_position

    def set_position(self,position):
        self._player_position.pop()
        self._player_position.append(position)

    def change_move_count(self,number):
        self.move_count += number

    def moves_remaining():
        return self.move_count

    def add_item(self,item):
        self._inventory.append(str(item))

    def get_inventory(self):
        return self._inventory
```

And when I try to run it, it calls NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a2.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._player = Player(GAME_LEVELS[dungeon_name])
NameError: name 'Player' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you for supplying an Error Traceback. However I cannot reproduce that error from your first snippet. When I add: `g = GameLogic()` I get no error, but the code runs just fine. I see from your traceback that the code is in `a2.py`. Is the `GameLogic` and `Player` both in this file?

Comment: Yes, the first piece of code is some kind of simplified a2.py, but they are not the same.     
I use this to see where goes wrong. The first piece of code seems work, but the a2.py returns the Error Traceback. I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Maybe I should post a complete code.

Comment: We need some more details to be able to reproduce the error,

Comment: btw, you have methods like: `can_collide()` which just call `super().can_collide()`. These are redundant since your class will inherit these by default.

Comment: OK, I will post my whole code as soon as possible. Your advice is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `Player` class in your code before you you initialize it.

As a side not, you do not need to write explicit getter or setter methods, since instance variables can be accessed and mutated by the `.` operator

Comment: Do you mean class GameLogic:
    self._player = Player(GAME_LEVELS[dungeon_name])
    def __init__(self, dungeon_name="game1.txt"):

Comment: I'm referring to your `get_position` and `get_inventory` methods. To access `inventory` or `position` simply call `Player._inventory` or `Player._player_position`